# The daily digest email is too wide, which makes it inappropriate for mobile devices

Tags: discussion, feature-request, email

I browse my emails using my phone. The daily digest email is very wide. Because the takes become so small, I have trouble reading it and this discourages me from reading my daily digest emails. I think decreasing the width or making it more appropriate for mobile devices would make it more readable for mobile device users.